# Can CoffeeScript/jQuery syntax be made simpler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I appreciate how the CoffeeScript syntax can help writing callbacks functions and make jQuery syntax much lighter. However, I'm still bothered by the classic `$(".foo")` construct: there are 6 symbols for only 3 "meaningful" characters! As far as I can tell, unfortunately, this syntax cannot be made simpler with CoffeeScript. Or can it? Do you have jQuery/CoffeeScript gem to share? Or are there some CoffeScript libraries designed to make jQuery usage even lighter?

As an exercise, could we make this code any simpler ?

```
$ ->                                        # nice!
  $('.menu').hide()                         # no benefit over JS ?
  $('.sub').hover -> 
    offset = $(@).offset()                  # $(@) is $(this) but the syntax feels awkward
    submenu = $(@).siblings "ul"            # optional parens...
    submenu.css 
      left: offset.left + $(@).outerWidth()
      top: offset.top
    submenu.show()                          # can't get rid of parenthesis ?
  , ->                                      # weird
    $(@).siblings("ul").hide()              # ...in this case, non-optional parens
```

Comment: You could probably omit the parentheses, but that will look ugly. It's important to know when you are running a jQuery selector - you should run them once per selector (where possible), and cache the results, which can then simplify your code to a var name...

Comment: I honestly don't understand why some programmers get fixated on CoffeeScript. As far as I can tell, programming in CS is like taking a calculus test with a pocket calculator -- it's certainly simpler, but only as long as you have simple problems to solve.

Comment: -- it's certainly simpler, but only as long as you have simple problems to solve -- Something similar could be said of Javascript, yet some people have managed to achieve impressive programming feats in JS... Anyway, I'm currently evaluating CS, it's shiny and pleasant, but I fear the lack of proper debugging, native browser support, tooling of the dev env, will drive me away quickly. Sad...

Comment: @solendil Yes, that's what I mean -- CS makes it easier to do easy things, and impossible to do difficult things. I'm not opposed to it -- everyone's welcome to use their favorite tools -- but I can't see any situation where it makes a really big job simpler.

Comment: @mblase75 From experience on a very large CS project, I can say that it is easier to do just about everything, and doesn't make anything more difficult.  (Worst case you drop into JS with backticks, but we've done that no more than 3 times.)  It makes a really big job simpler because its so much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your code to be perfectly good CoffeeScript as-is, solendil. You're doing a lot of different things in only a few lines, which is going to look a bit noisy in any language.

A few particulars:

1. The use of standalone `@` is divisive among CoffeeScripters. `this` behaves very differently from any other construction in JS, so I think it makes sense to give it a symbol that pops out and reminds you to ask: "Whoa, whoa, are you expecting me to mean the same thing that I did outside of this callback?"
2. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1407) that, if adopted, would allow you to write

   ```
   $(@).siblings("ul").hide()
   ```

   as

   ```
   $ @ .siblings "ul" .hide()
   ```

   which would also work with whitespace, like so:

   ```
   $ @
   .siblings "ul"
   .hide()
   ```

   You should go express your support.
3. As to parens on function calls with no arguments, the alternative is to write `do func`, which compiles to `func()`. I don't recommend this.

As to

> However, I'm still bothered by the classic `$(".foo")` construct: there are 6 symbols for only 3 "meaningful" characters!

How so? At the very least, `$` (a function name) and `.foo` (a selector string) make up 4 meaningful characters. And I haven't seen an alternative to string delimiters in any mainstream language. So I'd say that the meaningful character ratio there is pretty good. :)

Answer (score 2):

Coffeescript is just syntactical sugar (which I like, btw) for writing JS.  You can't get away from the object model that JS imposes on CS.

You can always do something like this:

```
menu = $ ".menu"
```

But that doesn't really buy you anything.

As far as your code example goes, you can write unreadable code in any language.  The equivalent code in JS will be even more unreadable (to someone who knows CS as well as they do JS).  You can make your code more readable by breaking up your callbacks into smaller pieces.  If you really wanted to, you might consider the sub-menu code being separated from the offset code... but not a big deal:

```
hoverIn = -> 
  offset = $(@).offset() 
  submenu = $(@).siblings "ul"            
  submenu.css 
    left: offset.left + $(@).outerWidth()
    top: offset.top
  submenu.show()  

hoverOut = -> $(@).siblings("ul").hide()

$ ->
  $('.menu').hide()                        
  $('.sub').hover hoverIn, hoverOut
```

This is a tip you can use in any language, however.

Comment: Yay! Your code has exactly the same # of lines than mine yet it is easier to read. Great. I have a problem however with the global namespace pollution when defining lots of named functions (hoverIn and hoverOut in your case). Would you have a solution to restrict their scope to where they're used?

Comment: @solendil You can namespace CS more or less the same way as JS; see [this](http://imulus.com/blog/casey/javascript/coffeescript-namespaces-modules-and-inheritance/) article.

Comment: By default, the code in a Coffeescript file is compiled to be hidden within the scope of the file.  In other words, everyting in the file is wrapped with `(function(){ //your code })();`.  Because of this, `hoverIn` and `hoverOut` will not be declared in the global scope.  You'd have to do something like `window.hoverIn = ` to pollute the global scope.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried writing readable code?

```
$(function () {
    function hover_in() {
        var offset = sub.offset();

        submenu.css({
            left: offset.left + sub.outerWidth(),
            top: offset.top
        }).show();
    }

    function hover_out() {
        submenu.hide();   
    }

    var sub = $(".sub"),
        submenu = sub.siblings("ul");

    sub.hover(hover_in, hover_out);
    $(".menu").hide();
});
```

If you want really aggressively terse code use a different language (perl, APL, LISP)